# Need help plotting 2D array in python. Im using Spyder(Python 3.6)

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib

Output of my program is

[[['AB', 'CD', 'EF', 'GH', 'AB'], ['CD', 'EF', 'AB', 'AB', 'AB'], ['AB', 'CD', 'AB', 'GH', 'AB']]

AB CD EF GH AB 
CD EF AB AB AB 
AB CD AB GH AB

Can I plot this in python? 
For example: Each row represents the time... I am using String outputs, and what are the different types of plots I can use in python other than Histogram?

Thank you!

Please help!

Comment: Plot what? You have a 2d list of strings. How do you intend to make a plot out of that?

Comment: You might get more help if you draw a sketch of the plot you are imagining.

Comment: Interesting output. Plot what frequency?

Comment: Output should be total number of "AB", 'CD', 'EF' and 'GH' over time_step of 1.

Comment: Better not use a `hist` as shown in one of the answers, instead use a bar plot,  `plt.bar(*numpy.unique(output, return_counts=True))` where output is defined as in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the best I can understand, you would want to plot the frequency of each string. For this, if your output is:

```
output = ['AB', 'CD', 'EF', 'GH', 'AB', 'CD', 'EF', 'AB', 'AB', 'AB', 'AB', 'CD', 'AB', 'GH', 'AB']
```

Then you can just use `hist`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.hist(output)
plt.xlabel('string')
plt.ylabel('count')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Done.. Worked perfectly! thanks!